# Why do I have to use type casting between objects with Content properties using a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I created a WPF project using Entity Framework and MSSQL.

The problem is when I want to display the content of id I have to typecast it to TextBlock because otherwise, I get an error message and I don't know what is the reason, why I have to do this.

This is the line that I am talking about:
`lblID.Content = ((TextBlock)id.Content).Text;`

Why can't I just write:`lblID.Content = id.Content;`
With this code when I load the DataGrid and select a row, the id value from the first column disappears and when the last one disappears too, a `NullReferenceException` will pop up:
[image: The value of the id disappears]

Here is my whole code:

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        hospitalEntities hp = new hospitalEntities();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeTable();
        }

        private void InitializeTable()
        {
            dgPatientTable.ItemsSource = null;
            var query = from patient in hp.patients
                        select
                        new
                        {
                            patient.ID,
                            patient.name,
                            patient.phone,
                            patient.email,
                            patient.address,
                            patient.postalZip
                        };
            dgPatientTable.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }

        private void btnAddPatient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (hp)
            {
                patient Patient = new patient()
                {
                    name = tbName.Text,
                    phone = tbPhone.Text,
                    email = tbEmail.Text,
                    address = tbAddress.Text,
                    postalZip = tbPostalZip.Text
                };
                hp.patients.Add(Patient);
                hp.SaveChanges();
                tbName.Text = "";
                tbPhone.Text = "";
                tbEmail.Text = "";
                tbAddress.Text = "";
                tbPostalZip.Text = "";
                InitializeTable();
            }
        }

        int patientId = 0;
        private void dgPatientTable_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                .ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid.SelectedIndex);
            DataGridCell id;
            try
            {
                id = (DataGridCell)dataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row).Parent;
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }

            lblID.Content = ((TextBlock)id.Content).Text;

            try
            {
                patientId = int.Parse(((TextBlock)id.Content).Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                patientId = 0;
                return;
            }
            DataGridCell name = (DataGridCell)dataGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row).Parent;
            tbNameUpdate.Text = ((TextBlock)name.Content).Text;
            DataGridCell phone = (DataGridCell)dataGrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row).Parent;
            tbPhoneUpdate.Text = ((TextBlock)phone.Content).Text;
            DataGridCell email = (DataGridCell)dataGrid.Columns[3].GetCellContent(row).Parent;
            tbEmailUpdate.Text = ((TextBlock)email.Content).Text;
            DataGridCell address = (DataGridCell)dataGrid.Columns[4].GetCellContent(row).Parent;
            tbAddressUpdate.Text = ((TextBlock)address.Content).Text;
            DataGridCell postalZip = (DataGridCell)dataGrid.Columns[5].GetCellContent(row).Parent;
            tbPostalzipUpdate.Text = ((TextBlock)postalZip.Content).Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're working with Visual elements, not the data they represent.

I don't have a complete understanding of the data types and architecture you are using. Therefore, my example is not the exact implementation, but showing the path to it.

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        hospitalEntities hp = new hospitalEntities();
        private readonly ObservableCollection<PatientEntity> patients = new(); 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Setting once after initialization XAML.
            dgPatientTable.ItemsSource = patients;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeTable();
        }

        private void InitializeTable()
        {
            patients.Clear();
            hp.patients.ToList().ForEach(p => patients.Add(p));
        }


        int patientId = 0;
        private void dgPatientTable_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            if(dataGrid.SelectedItem is PatientEntity patient)
            {
                // Some code that works with the selected patient.
            }
        }
```

You also work incorrectly with the Add and Update regions. But for the purpose of showing an example, the XAML of your layout matters.
Please post it in your question.

> I can't find the logic behind this line: lblID.Content = id.Content; and I just want to understand why it is not working. What is the reason?

Because from the ItemContainerGenerator you get not data (patient), but UI elements representing them. To get the data, you just need to extract it from dataGrid.SelectedItem and cast it to its original type. But you can't do it. Because your query returns you a list with an anonymous class. And you cannot cast SelectedItem to an anonymous class.

Therefore, you first need to create a collection for the source DataGrid.This collection must be of a named type so that you can cast SelectedItem to that type.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will post it, but can you explain the first sentence?  How can I work with Visual elements,  if I can see and change their data of them? Why don't I get an error message immediately after running the program? Why can I display the value of the ID until they are left?

Comment: @Kadam , The concept of WPF is built mainly on the fact that UI elements Represent data and get it themselves through bindings. You are only required to create these data sources. And the work of the code in such sources should be abstracted from the UI elements that are attached to them. Most often, the main data source is passed to the DataContext of the Window and is called the ViewModel.

Comment: For a more detailed example that better takes into account the implementation you already have, I need your complete code relevant to the question.
It would be convenient if you provided a link to the GitHub Repository with your Solution.

Comment: https://github.com/kadamQ/wpf_entity

Thank you so much. Actually, I know the code is bad, but I can't find the logic behind this line: `lblID.Content = id.Content;` and I just want to understand why it is not working. What is the reason?

Comment: @Kadam , Read the addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Kadam , There are many changes that need to be made to your solution in the Repository. Showing them all here in the topic would be inappropriate. If possible, please send me an invitation to contribute here https://github.com/EldHasp . Then I can commit and comment on the full changes in a way that is convenient for you. And here in the topic I will indicate only the main essential points.

Comment: @Kadam , I deleted service files and folders in the Repository. So that they are no longer sent to the Repository, I added an ignoring file to it. Also, for example, I added the ReadMe Repository description file. Change it as you see fit. For synchronization, it is best to clone the GitHub Repository on your computer to a new local folder. Then delete the old local folder if there are no necessary changes there.

Comment: I commited changes so that you have an understanding of how it is customary in WPF to compose a View, use bindings and work with data. I've made only minimal changes so you don't lose touch with your code. They will also show you the direction in which you should learn WPF.